# Getting error when i try to implement Native Ads in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, google-api, ads

I am trying to implement `AdMob` Native Ads in `relativelayout` but when i implement following line i get error.

```
private void addNativeExpressAds() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += 8) {
            NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(getActivity());
            adView.setAdUnitId("");
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(request);
        }
    }
```

My `Adapter`

```
public class RecGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecGridAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private final int mBackground;
    private List<Recipe> original_items = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Recipe> filtered_items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
    private static Context ctx;
    private ImageLoader imgloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


    private static final int ITEM = 0;
    private static final int AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
    int[] viewTypes;

    private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView name;
        public TextView bellow_name;
        public TextView duration1;
        public ImageView image;
        public CardView lyt_parent;

        private Typeface tf;
        private TextView news_date;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto-Bold.ttf");
            name.setTypeface(tf);

            bellow_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bellow_name);
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto.ttf");
            bellow_name.setTypeface(tf);

            news_date= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto.ttf");
            news_date.setTypeface(tf);

            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            lyt_parent = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
        }
    }

    public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecGridAdapter.ViewHolder {
        NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
        }
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }
    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public RecGridAdapter(Context ctx, List<Recipe> items) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        original_items = items;
        filtered_items = items;
        ctx.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
        mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public RecGridAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        switch (viewType) {

        case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.native_ad, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh1 = new ViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);
            return vh1;

        case ITEM:
            default:
            //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recipe, parent, false);
                 v.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
                 ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
          }
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

      int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
      switch (viewType) {
          case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
              NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder = (NativeExpressAdViewHolder)viewHolder;
              NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

              ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup)nativeExpressHolder.itemView;
              adCardView.removeAllViews();

              if (adView.getParent() != null) {
                  ((ViewGroup)adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
              }

              adCardView.addView(adView);
              break;

          case ITEM:
          default:
        final Recipe p = filtered_items.get(position);
         viewHolder.name.setText(p.name);
         viewHolder.bellow_name.setText(p.bellow_name);
         viewHolder.news_date.setText(p.news_date);
         imgloader.displayImage(Constant.getURLimgRecipe(p.image), viewHolder.image);
         viewHolder.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                     Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ActivityRecipeDetails.class);
                     i.putExtra(ActivityRecipeDetails.EXTRA_OBJCT, p);
                     ctx.startActivity(i);
                 }
             });
         //populate the RecyclerView
         //holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
         //holder.description.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());
    }
}

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filtered_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (position % 8== 0) ? AD_VIEW_TYPE: ITEM;
    }



    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final List<Recipe> list = original_items;
            final List<Recipe> result_list = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String str_title = list.get(i).name;
                String str_cat = list.get(i).category_name;
                if (str_title.toLowerCase().contains(query) || str_cat.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    result_list.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            results.values = result_list;
            results.count = result_list.size();
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filtered_items = (List<Recipe>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Code in `RecFragment.java`

```
public class RecFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipes, null);
        // activate fragment menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
         addNativeExpressAds ();
}

private void addNativeExpressAds() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += 8) {
            NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(getActivity());
            adView.setAdUnitId("");
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Error
[ERROR IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhQXd.png)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Could you show which line cause the problem and show the Logcat error info ?

Comment: Tell what error you got and specify the line. And also clarify why are you passing empty string rather than the actual ad-unit id? `adView.setAdUnitId("");`

Comment: @NabinBhandari i place error image please check

Comment: @NabinBhandari i remove id for just now but id is present in project.

Comment: @user8784273 In your RecFragment  where to show NativeAds